# Multivariate Forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I'm currently a MS student in statistics with very limited forecasting experience. I would like to find a model to predict grocery store department sales by week. I have a data set with about 2 years of weekly sales for 5 different grocery stores that I would like to fit the model on.

My question is, how do I handle the multiple departments? Do I need to use separate models on them? Or are there techniques for a multivariate model that I can use?

If you know of any good books or websites that have something to start with that would be a huge help.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're new to forecasting, you'll find this book of help: https://www.otexts.org/fpp. Make sure you take a look at it.

Comment: Also, Diebold ["Forecasting in Economics, Business, Finance and Beyond"](http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/Teaching221/Forecasting.pdf) is a nice resource (the textbook has incidentally been updated today).

Comment: Thanks for the book suggestions. I'll check both of them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically speaking you are better of dealing with each department separately for each separate store. In terms of frequency you might be much better off using daily data data and then (if you wish) sum the daily forecasts to weekly forecasts. The reason for this is that holidays will skew your weekly series. Long weekends around holidays can be treated with a daily model. More generally what we do on Monday is similar to what we did last Monday whereas what we do on week x is not necessarily similar to what we did on week x last year. That plus the confusion due to 52/53 weeks in the year results in generally poor accuracy using weekly data. In terms of a web example of daily data take a look at http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/intro-to-forecasting/doc_download/53-capabilities-presentation slide 45 as it lays out some ideas that you might find illuminating.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The holiday comment definitely makes sense for Christmas and other holidays that will land on the same day each year. But what about holidays like Memorial Day when the holiday can land in different weeks.

Comment: That is why you would prefer a daily model because the specificity of the daily indicator would point to the precise day. In addition to daily effects one might also need weekly effects and/or monthly effects.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It looks like I will have a lot of reading to do.